# Serialize form data to JSON with Dynamic Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, forms

I am trying to serialize my form data (name arrays) and so far I am only able to serialize the last object in the array. I can dynamically append a set of form fields and when I click submit it will still only append the new (last) object in the array. I've tried a lot of different ways to do this and this is the closest I've come. Here is the code in a playground - http://www.bootply.com/pv7fFLC1uJ. Example of what I would like to see:

```
{
  timeZonePicker: "-7",
  start: "09:00",
  end: "17:00",
  content: "San Francisco"
}
{
  timeZonePicker: "-3",
  start: "09:00",
  end: "17:00",
  content: "São Paulo"
}
```

HTML

```
<form class="form-inline fields_wrapper">
    <select class="form-control timeZonePicker" name="timeZonePicker[]" id="timeZoneId">
      <option value="-12" >(GMT -12:00) Eniwetok, Kwajalein</option>......
    </select>
    <input type="time" class="form-control start" name="start[]" value="">
    <input type="time" class="form-control end" name="end[]" value="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control content" name="content[]" value="">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(options) { 
    var data = $(this).serializeArray(), obj = {};   
    $.each(data, function(i, el) {
        console.log(data);
        var key = el.name;
        //remove the brackets from each html name array
        if (key.slice(-1) == "]") {
          key = key.slice(0,-2);
        }  
        if (el.name in options) {
            obj[options[key]] = obj[options[key]] || {};
            obj[options[key]][key] = el.value;
        }
        else {
            obj[key] = el.value;
        }
    });
    return obj;
};
```

Comment: Can you reduce the problem to something simpler? There's a lot going on with the code and the HTML and so on, so if it was a more streamlined form and code it would be easier to zero in on the real problem, and easier for others to groc everything involved.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I cleaned up the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating and returning an array. your object properties get overwritten in each iteration of each and you only return one object which is the last iteration

try (untested):

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(options) { 
    var data = $(this).serializeArray(), 
        // results array
        res = [];   
    $.each(data, function(i, el) {

      var obj={}

        console.log(data);
        var key = el.name;
        //remove the brackets from each html name array
        if (key.slice(-1) == "]") {
          key = key.slice(0,-2);
        }  
        if (el.name in options) {
            obj[options[key]] = obj[options[key]] || {};
            obj[options[key]][key] = el.value;
        }
        else {
            obj[key] = el.value;
        }

      res.push(obj)
    });
  // return array instead of the single object
    return res;
};
```

Whole thing would be a lot simpler if you gave wrapper of each row of data a common class and looped over those instead creating your own object without using `serializeArray()`

Comment: This returns the following: {{timeZonePicker: ""}, {start: ""}, {end: ""}, etc.}. But thank you for the help and I will try using your simpler suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As charlietfl said, you are returning just a single object, not an array.

The way you are doing it, you iterate through all objects that you have in the form at the same time. If you wish to go down that road, you have to know when you have created a single object, so you can add it into the array.

Here is a simple solution (not the prettiest one tho):

```
//build the json objects for each set of form fields
$.fn.serializeObject = function(options) { 
  var data = $(this).serializeArray(), obj = {}, all = []; 
    $.each(data, function(i, el) {
        var key = el.name;
        //remove the brackets from each html name array
        if (key.slice(-1) == "]") {
          key = key.slice(0,-2);
        }  
        if (el.name in options) {
            obj[options[key]] = obj[options[key]] || {};
            obj[options[key]][key] = el.value;
        }
        else {
            obj[key] = el.value;
        }

      if ((i + 1) % Object.keys(options).length == 0) {
        all.push(obj);
        obj = {};
      }
    });
    return all;
};
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I'll see if I can't find a prettier/simpler solution.